# Combine events or force one to fire before the other

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

Is there a way to combine two events into one?

For example a `click` event and `someObject.selection` event so I'll have access to both events' data? Both fire on a mouse click.

Alternatively, is there a way to guarantee one event firing before the other if both listen for a mouse click?

Comment: Are both events bound to the same element?

Comment: No, different elements. @DavidLamponDiestre

Comment: If you don't e.preventDefault() or e.stopBubbling() on the first event and both are on the same path from the e.target to the html element both will trigger. So you can process both with the event listeners. 

The event triggering will go from closest to e.target to the farthest.

I'd probably suggest using event delegation on the parent and using function calls. Maybe that would made the problem easier to solve.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, can you give an example please? @DavidLamponDiestre